# SQL Server : select price of all orders made by the customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, ssms

Basically, I have two SQL Server tables, `Customer` and `Orders`. On a per customer basis, I want to display customer's information and the price of all orders made by the customer.

Customer table:

[image: Customer Table]

Orders table:

[image]

Database diagram:

[image: Diagram]

This is my select function to get the price of all orders made by the customers.

```
select 
    Customer.CustomerID, 
    Customer.CustomerName, 
    Customer.CustomerAdress, 
    format(sum(Orders.Debit-Orders.Credit),'c', 'tr-TR') as Balance 
from 
    Customer 
join 
    Orders on Customer.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
           and Customer.CustomerName = Orders.CustomerName 
group by 
    Customer.CustomerID, 
    Customer.CustomerName,   
    Customer.CustomerAdress
```

It works fine. However, newly created customers don't have any orders yet, and this select doesn't return newly created customers.

I want to merge and display the customers who don't have any orders and set their balance as zero.

Comment: In your query replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Comment: Your image and SSMS tag suggest that you are using SQL Server.  I fixed the database tag.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all rows in one table, then you want an outer join or correlated subquery.

I also want to point out the use of table aliases to simplify the writing and reading of queries:

```
select c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, c.CustomerAdress, 
       format(sum(o.Debit - o.Credit), 'c', 'tr-TR') as Balance
from Customer c join
     Orders o
     on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID and 
        c.CustomerName = o.CustomerName
group by c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, c.CustomerAdress;
```

Storing the `CustomerName` in the `orders` table seems suspicious.  I would expect `CustomerId` to be the primary key of `Customers`.  That would make that name redundant at best and a source of error in most cases.